# How can I change the web view url with Kotlin through a button press?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have a web view in a different activity. I would like to open that activity and change the WebView that is contained within that activity to a specific url when a button is clicked.

```kotlin
val mwebViewArticle = webViewArticle
mwebViewArticle.loadUrl("http://www.google.com")
val intent = Intent(this, WebView::class.java)
this.startActivity(intent)
```

I am getting this error

```
2021-07-17 15:20:27.601 404-404/com.example.newsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.newsapp, PID: 404
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.newsapp.MainActivity$onCreate$3.onClick(MainActivity.kt:76)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Any specific error you are getting, what is the output of logcat?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not cleared from where you want to take web url?
here is how you can take url from edit text on run time and can use it in your webview

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener{
var URL = yourEditText.text.toString
loadWebView(URL)

}
```

In this loadWebView use this URL to load

```
private fun loadWebView(URL:String){

 if (URL != null) {

     yourWebView.loadUrl(URL)

   }
 }
}
```

Also add permission of internet in Manifest